# How can we send token to more than 1 wallet address at a time?

Tags: venomblockchain

I am trying to make an airdrop on Venom Chain and I am looking for some help. Everything else is pretty simple but I haven't found any string documentation on an airdrop kind of system

```
contract AirDrop {

    address private _owner;
    address[] private _recievers;

    function addWallet(address _walletAddress) external onlyOwner{
        _recievers.push(_walletAddress);
    }
    
    function transferToken(uint256 _amount) external  onlyOwner{
        // transfer TIP-3 to _recievers
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(_owner == msg.sender,12, "Error: Only owner");
        _;
    }
}
```

I tried to look in the [docs](https://docs.venom.foundation/build/development-guides/how-to-create-your-own-fungible-tip-3-token/venom-in-action/simple-tokensale) but it was complicated for a beginner. So what is the correct way to proceed with the `transferToken` function in order to send the token to multiple wallets at the same time